# Delay content loading on wordpress loop to speed up page

Tags: php, wordpress

i'm developing a real estate page, you can check it out [here](http://www.onecia.com.br/oneoff). As you can see, the page take some time to load, because it loads all the 50 apartments/houses at once.

To speed up the page, i want to know if there is any way to delay the load, so the page load faster.

Here is the loop code, i'm wondering what could work, for example if i put some "if/else" condition before the wordpress make a loop (while ( $newsLoop->have_posts() ) : $newsLoop->the_post();?>), but i don't know how to do it. The ideal for me is that the contents are loaded 3 on 3, or "row by row", once a row have 3 apartments.

```
<div class="portfolio-items2">
<?php

    $newsArgs = array(
        'post_type' => 'property',
        "orderby" => 'meta_value_num',
        "meta_key" => 'numerooff',
        "order" => 'DESC',
        'tax_query' => array(
            array(
                'taxonomy' => 'property-status',
                'field'    => 'slug',
                'terms'    => 'oneoff',
            )
        )
    );                   
    $newsLoop = new WP_Query( $newsArgs );                  
    while ( $newsLoop->have_posts() ) : $newsLoop->the_post();?>
        <div class="col-md-4 shortcode-col listing_wrapper <?php meta('seletoroff');?>" > 
            <div class="property_listing" data-link="http://www.onecia.com.br/imoveis-de-luxo/<?php /* Property ID if exists */ $property_id = get_post_meta($post->ID, 'REAL_HOMES_property_id', true); if(!empty($property_id)){ echo ''.$property_id; }?>">
                <div class="listing-unit-img-wrapper">
                    <div class="property_media">  </div>
                    <a href="http://www.onecia.com.br/imoveis-de-luxo/<?php /* Property ID if exists */ $property_id = get_post_meta($post->ID, 'REAL_HOMES_property_id', true); if(!empty($property_id)){ echo ''.$property_id; }?>">
                        <img width="525" height="350" src="<?php meta('imagemoff');?>" class="lazyload img-responsive wp-post-image" alt=""  sizes="(max-width: 525px) 100vw, 525px" />
                    </a>
                    <div class="tag-wrapper"><div class="featured_div"><?php meta('porcentooff');?></div></div>
                </div>
                <h4>
                        <a href="http://www.onecia.com.br/imoveis-de-luxo/<?php /* Property ID if exists */ $property_id = get_post_meta($post->ID,'REAL_HOMES_property_id', true); if(!empty($property_id)){ echo ''.$property_id; }?>">
                            <?php meta('titulooff');?>
                        </a>
                    </h4> 
                <div class="property_location_image">
                    <a href="http://www.onecia.com.br/imoveis-de-luxo/<?php /* Property ID if exists */ $property_id = get_post_meta($post->ID,'REAL_HOMES_property_id', true); if(!empty($property_id)){ echo ''.$property_id; }?>" rel="tag">
                        <span style="font-size: 15px;"><?php meta('bairrooff');?> </span>
                    </a>
                </div> 
                <br>     
                <div class="property_listing_details">
                   <?php
                        $post_meta_data = get_post_custom($post->ID);

                        if( !empty($post_meta_data['REAL_HOMES_property_size'][0]) ) {
                            $prop_size = $post_meta_data['REAL_HOMES_property_size'][0];
                                echo '<div class="inforoom">'. $prop_size .'m² <div class="info_labels"><img src="http://www.onecia.com.br/wp-content/themes/site2016/images/icon-size.png" style="max-width: 14%; height: auto;"></div></div>';
                            }

                        if( !empty($post_meta_data['REAL_HOMES_property_bedrooms'][0]) ) {
                                $prop_bedrooms = floatval($post_meta_data['REAL_HOMES_property_bedrooms'][0]);
                                $bedrooms_label = ($prop_bedrooms > 1)? __('Bedrooms','framework' ): __('Bedroom','framework');
                                echo '<div class="infobath">'. $prop_bedrooms .'<div class="info_labels"><img src="http://www.onecia.com.br/wp-content/themes/site2016/images/icon-bed.png" style="max-width: 17%; height: auto;"></div></div>';
                        }
                        if( !empty($post_meta_data['REAL_HOMES_property_bathrooms'][0]) ) {
                                $prop_bathrooms = floatval($post_meta_data['REAL_HOMES_property_bathrooms'][0]);
                                $bathrooms_label = ($prop_bathrooms > 1)?__('Bathrooms','framework' ): __('Bathroom','framework');
                                echo '<div class="infosize">'. $prop_bathrooms .'<div class="info_labels"><img src="http://www.onecia.com.br/wp-content/themes/site2016/images/icon-bath.png" style="max-width: 17%; height: auto;">
                                 </div></div>';
                        }
                    ?>
                </div>
                <div class="listing_unit_price_wrapper">
                    <span class="price_label price_label_before" style="text-decoration: line-through;">De: R$ <?php meta('valordeoff');?></span><br> 
                    <span style="text-decoration: underline; font-size: 22px; font-weight: bold;">Por: R$ <?php meta('valoroff');?> </span>
                     <span class="price_label"></span>
                </div>  
            </div>             
        </div> 
    <?php  endwhile; ?>
    </div>
```

I've already installed some plugins, but none of them worked.

Comment: This does not make any sense. Page needs to be loaded fully anyway. You need some caching mechanisms and/or reverse proxy to speed things up

Comment: For me it does. I have 50 apartments on a page, and i will have 80 tomorrow. If i had a way to load more when the user scroll, that would solution my problem got it?

Comment: Caching is good mechanism to speed up.. Also you can limit your query to 10 apartments and then use ajax pagination to show rest. I am sure this will helps you.

Comment: Pedro Have you checked out whether an "infinite scroll" plugin could be what you're searching for ? For example https://wordpress.org/plugins/ajax-load-more/ or this for woocommerce (in case it's relevant): https://wordpress.org/plugins/yith-infinite-scrolling/